# Adding features from a list to a sklearn classification model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a sklearn model that uses the character n-grams with Tf-Idf scheme to apply a classification task, as in this code:

```
model = Pipeline([
                ('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(3,5))),
                ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                ('clf', SGDClassifier(alpha = 0.0001,
                                           loss = 'log',
                                           epsilon = 7,
                                           max_iter=8,
                                           random_state = 40,
                                            tol = None))
               ])
gs_clf = model.fit(x, y)
predicted = gs_clf.predict(xDev)
print( 'Accuracy: ', accuracy_score(yDev, predicted))
```

The problem is:

The input data is tweets, I generated another new feature list manually "ex. number of words in a tweet that are positive", and the dimension of the new list is the same to the training matrix that created by sklearn model, I want to append the feature list horizontally to the matrix but I coudn't ..

I found some questions here in the site but non of them provide a clear answer ..

I tried to do this, but it not works:

```
model = Pipeline([
        ('feats', FeatureUnion([
                        pos,
                        neg,
                        ])),
                    ('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(3,5))),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                    ('clf', SGDClassifier(alpha = 0.0001,
                                               loss = 'log',
                                               epsilon = 7,
                                               max_iter=8,
                                               random_state = 40,
                                                tol = None))
                   ])
```

Comment: The pipeline operation may not work the way you expect it to, since it's designed to vectorize text features, but you're also contemplating adding pre-vectorized features features before it hits the pipeline. May be worth running some cross val without the pipeline to verify it outperforms just the tweets data.

Comment: My idea is not to look for which perform better, but to learn how to achieve such a way ..